# Software that can recognize the paragraph structure of a scanned handwritten text

Tags: windows, images

I have a lot of handwritten lecture notes that I scanned and stored on my computer. I am looking for a software that can analyse a document and decompose it into smaller parts like paragraphs. A couple of requirements I would like (more or less in decreasing order of preferences):

Requirements:

1. My OS are Windows 7 and 10.
2. Automatic. I mean I can cut the document myself using a image processing software like Gimp. Actually, with cut and paste, I can actually do it manually with Paint. My goal is to find something where I can just select one or several documents (image or maybe PDF), a few parameters, and then go for a beer while my computer is working for me.

Preferences:

1. Free, or relatively cheap. Or at least a long trial period, so that I have time to use it and motivate my department head to buy a license.
2. If the software can somehow manage some additional structure of the text, that would be a nice asset. I can't precise what I mean by "additional structure", but my goal is to work on notes for maths lectures with clear paragraph headers like definitions, examples, proofs, so a software that might identify this in some way.
3. This question does not ask about an OCR that would convert the text. But I guess that some OCR softwares may have structure recognitions possibilities.
4. I would prefer to avoid to have to buy dedicated hardware (some scanners may have an option to cut white/uniform background areas).

Edit (to answer comments): I systematically leave a white space between paragraphs. My indentation is inconsistant. I use nonlined white paper. If lining (or other writing habits that can easily be changed) matters, I would be interested in hearing your suggestions, at least for later use

#### Example

[image: example]

The black lines on the second picture represent where I expect the document to be cut (I realized that my handwriting is not horizontal. Lined paper may help to improve this).

[image: Same example, but now with black lines as paragraph separator]

Comment: @Taladris - I have added a new answer that demos using (i)python to do the job - I did twist your paragraphs to be roughly as if written on lined paper first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Spilt Handwritten Paragraphs

*Software Recommendations does not render iPython notebooks so you can see the rendered, by nbviewer, version of this code [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/kxq9683jmdzjm9f/SlicePicture.ipynb)* or of a cleaned up version [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/7ohw2daqqg05bk5/SlicePicture2.ipynb?dl=0).

**N.B.** The example page in the question was written on unlined paper so the paragraphs were at all angles - this was edited so that the text was at right angles to the left border by hand.  While it would be possible to add to the code here so as to group the text, detect the angles and do the rotation a **much** simpler solution is to use lined paper.

## For Python 2.6+ and Python 3.x compatibility
    from **future** import print_function

```
## Import the tools that we will use
from scipy import ndimage, misc  # Used for image manipulations
import numpy as np  # The heavy lifter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Mostly used for debug & illistration displays

sample = misc.imread('Sample.jpg')  # Read in the image

# Lets have a display so that we know we have the image loaded OK!
plt.imshow(sample, aspect='auto')  # Create a plot
ax = plt.gca()  # Get the axis
ax.tick_params(length=0, labelbottom="off", labelleft="off")  # Hide the ticks & labels
print(sample.shape)  # Lets see the dimentions while we are at it
```

[image]
 (2340, 1654, 3)

```
# Define some functions that we might need
def rgb2mono(rgb):
    """ Convert image to monochrome."""
    return rgb.sum(2) > 450 # Sum the 3rd (Colour) Axis and convert to True/False 450 is an arbetary number

bw = rgb2mono(sample)  # Get a black and white version of the image, this is quicker to manipulate
plt.imshow(bw, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), aspect='auto') # Show the black & white version
ax = plt.gca()  # Get the axis so we can
ax.tick_params(length=0, labelbottom="off", labelleft="off") # Turn off the ticks & lables
print (bw.shape) # You can see that this is smaller and simpler than before
```

(2340, 1654)
[image]

```
y,x = bw.shape  # Get the layout
inkyrows = bw.sum(1)!=x  # Count the white pixells and if they are not ALL white there must be some ink
del bw # We have finished with the B/W image now
print (y,x,sum(inkyrows))  # Debug output
occ_rows = [n for n in xrange(len(inkyrows)) if inkyrows[n]]  # Get a list of the rows with some ink
# Now we need to find the mid point of each blank section
midgaps = [(occ_rows[n]+occ_rows[n+1])//2 for n in xrange(len(occ_rows)-1) if (occ_rows[n+1]-occ_rows[n])>6]  # more than 6 lines are blank
print('Gaps', ', '.join([str(x) for x in midgaps]))  # Debug output
```

2340 1654 1898
Gaps 181, 486, 752, 776, 1098, 1432, 1571, 1789, 1916, 2016, 2158
Note that the first gap and last gap may be mid way between the first/last text and the edge of the page.  Lets see:

```
#  A redline display

img1 = plt.imshow(sample, aspect='auto')  # Create a plot
img1.autoscale()
for line in midgaps:
    plt.axhline(y=line, color='r')
ax = plt.gca()  # Get the axis
ax.tick_params(length=0, labelbottom="off", labelleft="off")  # Hide the ticks & labels
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Looking Good so far!** And they are not - we are going to have to manually add them, ok so we are going to get a blank paragraph about a 3rd of the way down but that should be acceptable.

```
# We need to add the first and last sections to the list
sample2 = sample.copy()
(y,x,c) = sample2.shape  # reget the shape
sectionlines = [0,]  # start at the top edge
sectionlines.extend(midgaps)  # Add the gaps
sectionlines.append(y)  # Add the bottom edge
no_sections = len(sectionlines)-1  # Get the number of sections
print (no_sections)
sections = [sample2[sectionlines[n]:sectionlines[n+1]] for n in xrange(no_sections)] 
#img1 = plt.imshow(sections[-1], )#aspect='auto')  # Create a plot when debugging
#img1.autoscale()

#  Time to save the results
for n in xrange(no_sections):
    misc.imsave("output_%02d.jpg" % n, sections[n])
```

## The results

1[image]

2[image]

3[image]

Skip the blank one
5[image]

6[image]

7[image]

8[image]

9[image]

10[image]

11[image]

12[image]

### Running on Original Sample

Out of curiosity I tried running this on the original sample and it came very close, (red-lined image only shown for brevity).
[image: Original Red-Lined]

### Summary

I have uploaded the ipython notebook, a html version of the notebook for anybody that doesn't have ipython installed yet, a standalone python file that does the same, *given the requisite libraries*, and all the images to [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0en9qeue0247456/AAANEk8YwdbjM3G-i8VQQs-0a?dl=0) on Dropbox.  Obviously this code could be improved on, made more flexible and could be expanded to straighten lines of text automatically rather than relying on them already being straight.

Note that this solution is operating system independent, free, and should work with a number of image file formats - I have not tested it with pdf files though.  It relies on [python](http://python.org), [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) & [scipy](http://scipy.org/) but for development and debugging I also used [ipython](http://ipython.org) & [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) but these can potentially be dispensed with.

### The Updated Code

```
# coding: utf-8

# Spilt Handwritten Paragraphs
# ---
# This notebook is an attempt to address [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23034/software-that-can-recognize-the-paragraph-structure-of-a-scanned-handwritten-tex/23071?noredirect=1#comment33707_23071) Software Recommendations question. While it was written for handwritten documents it should work even better for typewritten or printed documents.
# 
# **N.B.** The example page in the question was written on unlined paper so the paragraphs were at all angles - this is Original.jpg but in Sampe.jpg this was edited, by hand with gimp, so that the text was at right angles to the left border.  While it would be possible to add to the code here so as to group the text, detect the angles and do the rotation a **much** simpler solution is to use lined paper.

# In[1]:
# For compatibility with both Python 2.6+ & 3.x 
from __future__ import print_function

## Import the tools that we will use
from scipy import ndimage, misc  # Used for image manipulations
import numpy as np  # The heavy lifter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Mostly used for debug & illistration displays
import sys, os


# In[2]:

## iPython magic to display figures inline rather than seperate windows - Don't need this in the python file.
if 'ipykernel' in sys.argv[0]:
    get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')


# In[3]:

def GetImage(filename):
    """ Get the image and generate the output template."""
    parts = filename.split('.')  # Split on .
    parts[-2] = parts[-2] + "_%02d"  # add the formating to the last part but one
    outname_template = '.'.join(parts)  # Join it back up
    image = misc.imread(filename)  # Read the image
    return image, outname_template  # Return image and outname


# In[11]:

def ShowImage(image, redlines=None, cmap=None, caption=None):
    """ Show the image with optional readlines."""
    if redlines is None:
        redlines = []
    img1 = plt.imshow(image, #aspect='auto',
                      cmap=cmap)  # Create a plot
    img1.autoscale()
    for line in redlines:
        plt.axhline(y=line, color='r')
    ax = plt.gca()  # Get the axis
    ax.tick_params(length=0, labelbottom="off", labelleft="off")  # Hide the ticks & labels
    ax.set_title(caption)
    plt.show()


# In[5]:

# Define some functions that we might need

def rgb2mono(rgb):
    """ Convert image to monochrome."""
    return rgb.sum(2) > 450 # Sum the 3rd (Colour) Axis and convert to True/False 450 is an arbetary number


# In[6]:

def GetGaps(image, threshold=6):
    """ Get the gaps in the image that are bigger than a given threshold."""
    bw = rgb2mono(image)  # Convert to black & white
    y,x = bw.shape  # Get the layout
    inkyrows = bw.sum(1)!=x  # Count the white pixels and if they are not ALL white there must be some ink
    del bw # We have finished with the B/W image now
    occ_rows = [n for n in xrange(len(inkyrows)) if inkyrows[n]]  # Get a list of the rows with some ink
    # gaps are any missing sections more than threshold lines that are blank
    midgaps = [(occ_rows[n]+occ_rows[n+1])//2 for n in xrange(len(occ_rows)-1) if (occ_rows[n+1]-occ_rows[n])>threshold] 
    return midgaps


# In[7]:

def SplitSections(image, threshold=6, showredline=False):
    """ Split the image into sections - need to add top and bottom to the list."""
    (y,x,c) = image.shape
    sectionlines = [0,]  # start at the top edge
    gaps = GetGaps(image, threshold)  # Get the gaps
    if showredline:
        ShowImage(image, redlines=gaps, caption="Red-Line")
    sectionlines.extend(gaps)  # Add the gaps
    sectionlines.append(y)  # Add the bottom edge
    no_sections = len(sectionlines)-1  # Get the number of sections
    sections = [image[sectionlines[n]:sectionlines[n+1]] for n in xrange(no_sections)]  # Do the split
    return sections


# In[13]:

def Split_File(filename, threashold=6, show=False, showresults=False):
    """ Split and save a named file."""
    image, outname_base = GetImage(filename)  # Get the image and the output name template
    if show:
        ShowImage(image, caption=filename)  # For demo purposes show the orginal
    sections = SplitSections(image, threashold, show) # Split it into sections
    for n in xrange(len(sections)):  # Index on the sections
        name = outname_base % n  # Make the name
        misc.imsave(name, sections[n])  # Save the image
    if showresults:  # demo section
        for n in xrange(len(sections)):  # Index of sections
            ShowImage(sections[n], caption="%s Section %d" % (filename, n))  # Show them


# In[15]:

def Demo(showresults=False):
    """ Do the demo."""
    for filename in ['Sample.jpg', 'Original.jpg']:  # List of demo files
        if os.path.exists(filename):  # If it is there
            Split_File(filename, show=True, showresults=showresults)  # Process it and show the results


# In[16]:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if 'ipykernel' in sys.argv[0]:
        Demo(True)
    elif len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print(""" Usage:\n\tSupply one or more filenames on the command line.""")
        Demo()
    else:
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
            print("Processing", arg)
            Split_File(arg)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will need some time to understand how to use Python but the results you obtained are a great motivation. I bought lined paper today hehe. By the way, is there any particular reason you used Python over another language?

Comment: Lots of reasons I use python: Free, Cross Platform, Interactive, Batteries ARE included, you can start getting great results very quickly, lots of online resources and examples, works with other software, etc. - at work last week I replaced 5 days work, _that had yet to produce the required result_, by an experienced VB developer with 6 lines of python.  One of the nice things is that the above code will work on Windows _once python & numpy are installed_, OS-X and Linux _usually without installing anything_.  Also the download sizes - the above requires less than 100 MB - MS-VS=5-7GB

Answer (score 4):

As long as your handwritten notes follow a reasonably consistent pattern you could take the view that a line with no ink on it marks a paragraph break, i.e. a point where you would like the image split.  [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) or [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) with a script written in [Python](http://python.org) could do this by loading the image, reducing the colors to isolate the ink, then

- in OpenCV using a histogram of the vertical axis blocks of (near) zeros longer than some threshold would mark a paragraph break.
- in numpy the image is an array, summing on the vertical would give a value for the amount of ink, again a set of very low values for more than a given number of rows would indicate where to split the image.

In either case you would then use the calculated pixel row to split the original image into one per paragraph.

You could possibly also come up with a pipe of commands for [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) that would follow basically the same steps, filter to ink, sum along the long edge, look for gaps above a given width to get the pixel rows to split on, split.

Comment: I understand the principles of these ideas but I am far from being able to implement them

Comment: The biggest issue that I can see is that the paragraphs are not straight on the page, in some cases the bottm of the end of the last line of one paragraph is vertically lower than the top of the first character on the succeeding paragraph.  I think that we would need to try to straighten the lines, _or switch to lined paper_.

Comment: I was thinking I should give some news: the code works very well, even with non lined paper. I didn't know Python before asking the question but in a short time, the code becomes transparent. A small error to mention (maybe a problem of Python version): the print function needs parentheses to work. 

The only two problems I faced when using it: sometimes blank areas are not cut, I guess it is a paper problem or a scan problem. Also, sometimes the picture is rotated without any reason.

Comment: @Taladris Great to hear - the print problem is simple - I wrote the code in Python 2.7 and you are using Python 3 - I have updated the code at the link above to handle that.  Regarding the rotation problem it is probably the picture orientation information from the scanner or camera - if you have two files one of which has the problem I can take a look _assuming no confidential content of course_.